# What will cause high accuracy but a big loss?

Tags: machine-learning, training, loss-function, accuracy

In the question of [What is the relationship between the accuracy and the loss in deep learning?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42599/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-accuracy-and-the-loss-in-deep-learning?newreg=af85adb2db374db6b7b4474cefbf2eaa), @Jérémy Blain gave a fantastic interpretation of 'relationship' between accuracy and loss:

- 1 - low accuracy and big loss means you made huge errors on a lot of data
- 2 - low accuracy but small loss means you made little errors on a lot of data
- 3 - high accuracy with small loss means you made low errors on a few data (best case)
- 4 - high accuracy but a big loss, means you made huge errors on a few data.

As I understand,

- 1 - implies bad algorithm 'in most of time'
- 2 - implies overfitting
- 3 - is what we want

Questions are:

```
 1   Any other reasons caused 1 and 2?
 2   what will lead to case 4 : high accuracy but a big loss?
```

Comment: Regarding your question no.2 - it means that the model is very good, well predicts almost all instances, but there are some outliers of a huge impact on the loss.

Comment: @GrzegorzSionkowski,thanks,outliers will be big reason for high acc but big loss.