# Cross Validation in Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, cross-validation

I am training a neural network and doing 10-fold cross validation to measure performance. I have read lots of documentation and forums telling that the set of weights that should be saved or checkpointed are the ones that results to lowest `val_loss` and not highest `val_accuracy`, since the former usually results to higher testing accuracy.

Out of curiosity, I checkpointed both highest `val_accuracy` and lowest `val_loss` during my training. However, I found out that for some folds, I am getting better testing accuracy when I use the set of weights with highest `val_accuracy` compared to lowest `val_loss`. So during my cross-validation, I chose the set of weights that resulted to higher testing accuracy regardless of whether it came from the highest `val_accuracy` or lowest `val_loss`, and then just averaged the resulting testing accuracy across the 10 folds.

Is my methodology valid?

Comment: This might help: [Should I prefer the model with the lowest validation loss or the highest validation accuracy to deploy?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/17975/should-i-prefer-the-model-with-the-lowest-validation-loss-or-the-highest-validat)

Comment: Also, [What is the relationship between the accuracy and the loss in deep learning?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42599/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-accuracy-and-the-loss-in-deep-learning#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20relationship%20between,you%20made%20on%20the%20data.)