# Why my network needs so many epochs to learn?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, model-selection, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm working on a relation classification task for natural language processing and I have some questions about the learning process. I implemented a convolutional neural network using PyTorch, and I'm trying to select the best hyper-parameters.

The common behaviour I noticed is that even after 1000 epochs, my validation loss is still slowly decreasing, and my metric (macro F1 score) is slowly increasing. Both the metrics are oscillating, perhaps due to the imbalance of the 4 classes to classify (5%, 3%, 30%, 62%). I'm using Adam, so the learning rate is not set by myself (it is adaptive). I'm using dropout 0.5 after max pooling, and mini batches of size 50.

[image: The train and validation loss during the 1000 epochs]
[image: The macro f1 score during the 1000 epochs]

On books and online tutorials I have seen plots that are so clear in when to stop training. For instance, when the train loss becomes less that the validation loss, or when a plateau is reached in the validation loss. This seems not to be the case, so I'm asking for an advice to more navigated neural network users:

- Why the network is still learning after so many epochs (and so slowly)? It is a reasonable behaviour? Do I need to run the model for 2000, or even 3000 epochs to get the best macro f1 score? It risks to overfit, doesn't it?
- My network is fed by word embeddings and position embeddings only, so I'm wondering if this behaviour can be motivated by (i) a network architecture that is too complex for the task, (ii) a network architecture that is too simple to model the complexity for the task, (iii) the inputs are not so informative to discriminate the classes, so the network learns with difficulty (and thus slowly). My network architecture is not deep: it has an embedding layer + conv layer + max-pool layer + softmax.
- A side question: suppose 1000 epochs are enough. When I need to compare performance of many models (or to compare different hyper-parameter combinations), which score I need to pick and compare? The "last best" f1 score (say at epoch 980) or the last reported score (i.e., the one at epoch 1000)?

Do you have any suggestions? Let me know if something is unclear!

=====

**Update**

Following the advice by **Djib2011** I trained the network with different learning rates, in particular `lr=0.001` (the default), `lr=0.01`, `lr=0.1`. I trained the network using even more epochs (i.e., 3000), to identify the moment in which I could stop the training. What I noticed is that increasing the learning rate doesn't help, and the best results are given by the default `lr=0.001`. However it is still unclear when to stop.

Do you have other advices to tackle this problem? Besides learning rates, there could be other issues behind the optimizer (e.g., network with a small capacity)? Thank you in advance!

[image: Report using different learning rates]

=====

**Update #2**

After experimenting with different optimization algorithms (i.e., RMSProp, AdaDelta, Adamax, SGD) with different learning rates and 3000 epochs, I noticed that the behaviour across these different settings was still the same (no convergence, and many epochs with little decreasing training and validation losses).

I thus modified the pytorch implementation by moving the 3 lines: `optimizer.zero_grad()`, `loss.backward()`, `optimizer.step()` inside the (training) batches loop instead of running them after the loop. As a result, this is the edited code that performs training and testing at each epoch:

```
# Iterate over epochs
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs+1):
    train_loss = 0
    model.train()

    train_predictions = []
    train_true_labels = []

    # Iterate over training batches
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs, labels = Variable(inputs).to(device), Variable(labels).to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad() # set gradients to zero

        preds = model(inputs)
        preds.to(device)

        # Compute the loss and accumulate it to print it afterwards
        loss = loss_criterion(preds, labels)
        train_loss += loss.detach()

        pred_values, pred_encoded_labels = torch.max(preds.data, 1)
        pred_encoded_labels = pred_encoded_labels.cpu().numpy()

        train_predictions.extend(pred_encoded_labels)
        train_true_labels.extend(labels)

        loss.backward()       # backpropagate and compute gradients
        optimizer.step()      # perform a parameter update


    # Evaluate on development test
    predictions = []
    true_labels = []
    dev_loss = 0

    model.eval()
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(dev_loader):
        inputs, labels = Variable(inputs).to(device), Variable(labels).to(device)

        preds = model(inputs)
        preds.to(device)

        loss = loss_criterion(preds, labels)
        dev_loss += loss.detach()

        pred_values, pred_encoded_labels = torch.max(preds.data, 1)
        pred_encoded_labels = pred_encoded_labels.cpu().numpy()

        predictions.extend(pred_encoded_labels)
        true_labels.extend(labels)
```

I thus trained again the network using my default configuration (Adam, lr=0.001) and surprisingly I obtained a convergence at epoch 22 (see images below). I think the issue was there, do you agree? Do you have any additional advice? Thanks again!

[image]
[image]

Comment: One reason is maybe the choice of learning rates from Adam leads to too small learning rates, which make learning slow. You can try to use Backtracking gradient descent, which is less complicated and is also adaptive.

Answer (score 4):

**My opinion**:

You should try to increase the **learning rate** of your model (or even other parameters of your optimizer - e.g. momentum).

**To answer your questions**:

> Why the network is still learning after so many epochs (and so slowly)? It is a reasonable behaviour? Do I need to run the model for 2000, or even 3000 epochs to get the best macro f1 score? It risks to overfit, doesn't it?

Yes from what I can tell your model is still learning (evident by the fact that your validation loss is still dropping). It definitely needs more epochs to get the best performance.

> My network is fed by word embeddings and position embeddings only, so I'm wondering if this behaviour can be motivated by (i) a network architecture that is too complex for the task, (ii) a network architecture that is too simple to model the complexity for the task, (iii) the inputs are not so informative to discriminate the classes, so the network learns with difficulty (and thus slowly). My network architecture is not deep: it has an embedding layer + conv layer + max-pool layer + softmax.

Generally speaking, larger networks need more time to converge. However the model you describe is pretty small so it shouldn't take too long.

> A side question: suppose 1000 epochs are enough. When I need to compare performance of many models (or to compare different hyper-parameter combinations), which score I need to pick and compare? The "last best" f1 score (say at epoch 980) or the last reported score (i.e., the one at epoch 1000)?

If you want to compare performance, you should compare the best f1 for each model. If you want to compare convergence speed then you could compare the f1 at X epochs.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the detailed response! I updated the description with tests using different learning rates. It seems the default lr value leads to the best results, and also after 3000 epochs the val loss is still decreasing. Do you have other advices on this behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: You could try another optimizer altogether (e.g. adadelta, rmsprop). An excellent overview of optimization algorithms can be found [here](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/). Other than that, are you sure that the algorithm takes all samples into account at each epoch? (i.e. `steps_per_epoch * batch_size = num_samples)`

Comment: Thank you, again! I tried with other optimization algorithms but the behaviour is still the same. You made me doubt about the implementation so I checked and I tried to move the backpropagation step inside the train batch loop. I updated the question with the results and the code snippet. It seems the problem was really there, in the implementation, what do you think about it? Do you have any other advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is quite self explanatory. One small thing I would like to add that too many epochs may lead to overfitting. The model will keep learning as many epochs we may allow. So there must be a limit to the number of epochs.

Comment: That's why you have callbacks :)

Comment: Thank you! However, it seems quite difficult to decide when to stop (see the updated question with experiments with 3000 epochs).

Comment: The epochs may be continued as long as both the Train and Test plots run in parallel. The moment the plots start to bifurcate from each other, it may be inferred that the model is going to suffer from overfitting beyond this point.

Comment: The best validation loss in this model occurs well before the intersection of the train and test plots.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comment, you may try to use Backtracking Gradient descent, which automatically choses learning rates for you, and for which convergence can be rigorously proven under the weakest possible assumptions until now. For details you can see my answer in this link:

[Does gradient descent always converge to an optimum?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24534/does-gradient-descent-always-converge-to-an-optimum/40644#40644)

There, you can also find links to some source codes on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you! However, I firstly desire to figure out how to fix the behaviour in a more general setting. I will surely try backtracking GD afterwards. If you have some suggestions, besides the optimization, I appreciate a lot.